# "Более чем девяностО процентов" или "более чем девяностА процентов"

Tags: склонение, падежи, числительные

*Квалифицированное применение данной теории позволяет обеспечить действительное выздоровление более чем девяносто(-а) процентов пациентов.*

Знаю, что в именительном и винительном падежах окончание -О, во всех остальных -А. Но не могу сообразить, какой вопрос задать от *более чем*: чего? или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Роман, тут вопрос не от *более чем* (тогда был бы именительный падеж: «более чем *что*?»), а от *выздоровления*. Обеспечить выздоровление... ну? Выздоровление *кого*? же! Так что падеж у дополнения — родительный.

И, естественно, в счётном обороте склоняется только числительное. Так что — *выздоровление более чем девяност**а** процентов*.

Comment: Спасибо, Егор. Я думал о выздоровлении. Но меня смутила длинная цепочка: выздоровления (кого?) пациентов, а они зависят от процентов, а те от девяноста, да вдобавок еще и более чем. :)

Comment: Ну да, цепочки бывают и ещё длиннее :) И да, иногда их длина сказывается. Как писал ещё Пушкин по поводу того, что в конце фразы «Я ему не могу  позволить начать писать...» просится, конечно, «стихи», а не «стихов» (это точная цитата из Пушкина, как ни трудно в это поверить!): «Неужто электрическая сила отрицательной частицы должна пройти сквозь всю эту цепь глаголов и отозваться на существительном? Не думаю». Но тут другое: тут два равноправных варианта. А выздоровление бывает только «кого», без вариантов.

Answer (score 3):

*Квалифицированное применение данной теории позволяет обеспечить действительное выздоровление более **девяноста** процентов пациентов.* Это родительный падеж, окончание -А.

Я полагаю, что местоимение ЧЕМ здесь **не является обязательным**.

Например: Обеспечить выздоровление (кого?) ста пациентов, более ста пациентов, более чем ста пациентов. В данном случае у местоимения "чем" нет полезной нагрузки, сравнить: более чем на десять процентов, более чем у ста пациентов.

В заданном предложении **текст и так перегружен** и читается сложно, в том числе с точки зрения фонетики (проценты – пациенты): *выздоровление более чем девяноста процентов пациентов.*

Comment: Действительно, *чем*  можно убрать. Спасибо.