# О правильности употребления сочетания "более чем" с числовыми оборотами

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, фразеология

*Не хватает **более** десяти книг. Не хватает **более чем** десяти книг.*

Оба предложения выглядят грамматически верными, но какова тогда роль местоимения **«чем»** в подобных конструкциях, где оно не кажется необходимым?

Фигура речи, дополнительная коннотация оборота? Или что?

Также см. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467466/Более-чем-девяностО-процентов-или-более-чем-девяностА-процентов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467466/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%90-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Чем" используется как связка, когда напрямую с "более" оно не стыкуется.
А здесь с "чем" более подчёркивается нехватка — более подходит восклицательный знак. При прочтении этого варианта как просто констатации (не хватает, а это меня не касается) "чем" у меня звучит избыточно.
Также с "чем" возможен другой падеж:
*— Не хватает десять книг.

— Нет, не хватает бОлее, чем десять книг.* || При таком возражении "чем" необходимо.

Comment: У меня, кстати, была такая мысль. Я сначала написала: "Из фонда пропало более ста редких книг".  Но  это какое-то дежурное сообщение, безо всякой экспрессии и сожалений по поводу утраченного. "Из фонда пропало более ЧЕМ ста редких книг!"  И здесь уже ясно, как это всех огорчило. Действительно, местоимение «чем» вносит определенную коннотацию, подчеркивает нехватку.

Comment: Да, вообще, сложный вопрос. Не зразу это понял, пришлось долго анализировать.

Comment: Тогда будем считать тему закрытой, спасибо вам за ответ.

Comment: Здесь ещё не всё чисто. У меня почему-то "более чем ст**а**" не звучит, а звучит "ст**о**", как и "более чем миллион". У вас тоже звучит "более чем миллион**а**"? Как-то с большими числами "чем" плохо стыкуется.

Comment: Да, надо еще подумать... Здесь какой-то конфликт падежей: "более" требует Р.п., а "чем" – В.п.  Иногда он не очень заметен, а иногда проявляется яснее.

Comment: *Из фонда пропало более чем миллиона рублей.* У вас звучит окончание -а? У меня нет. В какой-то мере здесь "чем" даже мешает.

Comment: Вероятно, при оценке больших сумм "чем" не несет уже полезной информации и становится лишним.  Непонятна величина "более чем" - это десятки, сотни, тысячи или что?

Comment: У меня уже при "сто" не звучит. А с "тысячей" лучше. Возможно, что это зависит от слов (традиции), а не от величины.

Comment: Ага, в вашем примере "редких" мешает. Так нормально звучит: *Из фонда пропало более чем тысячи книг.* То есть мешает распространение.

Comment: Распространение тоже может уменьшать конфликт падежей. Вероятно, здесь влияют разные факторы.

Comment: По ходу, распространение способствует сравнению и винительному падежу, то есть увеличивает конфликт.

Answer (score 2):

Я думал, "более чем" не с числовыми оборотами употребляется. К примеру: ты меня более чем удивил. Нельзя ж сказать *ты меня более удивил.*
Обычное слово, смысл от него иногда меняется, а иногда нет.

Comment: Andrew,  спасибо за ответ. Сочетание «более чем» употребляется в различных случаях (можно посмотреть в словаре), но сейчас нас интересует только числовые обороты. Сравниваем два предложения. Значение вроде бы одинаковое, но тогда зачем мы используем местоимение «чем», если вполне можем без него обойтись? 
Вот  загадка, ведь лишних слов в языке не бывает. Каждое слово что-то меняет или добавляет. Вы знаете ответ? Необязательно искать его в книгах, можно просто догадаться. Изменилось ли значение предложения ? Или мы  добавляем слово  «чем»  по ошибке, сам не зная почему?

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта. Только скажите это составителям ЕГЭ)

Comment: Да, ЕГЭ – это такой монстр, чу́дище о́бло, озо́рно, огро́мно, стозе́вно. Но вот кончится учеба, начнется взрослая и ответственная жизнь с экзаменами по своим предметам: логика, интуиция, наблюдательность, быстрота мышления, умение принимать решения. К этому-то  вы готовы? :)  Вот и проверьте себя. Вопрос не требует глубоких знаний, но вот никто на него не отвечает (или неинтересно, или не хотят). А здесь нужно всего лишь умение мыслить.  Попробуйте  – и вопрос ваш. Все творческое и нестандартное приветствуется.